# Docker on Ubuntu not cleaning up aufs diff

Tags: ubuntu, docker

I have been tinkering with Docker (17.06.1-ce) on a Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Virtual Machine.

I am building and removing .Net Core 2 SDK containers, which are like 1.5G large. After some time I completely ran out of disk space. After some investigation the /var/lib/docker/aufs/diff folder was full of data, inside folders like:

```
e17ba29a05457b2ae9acaa69aa3220b5375d9fe7bcef3abade5a7efe022a96db-init-removing
e17ba29a05457b2ae9acaa69aa3220b5375d9fe7bcef3abade5a7efe022a96db-removing
f88f1f45157e4e19c2c77321b54e6856d22501443b79ed77d785385f54e52cf8-removing
fa3cf511441251f0a5a555b8867b08767a2afd3ee4a8fa76a264d5a1a004843f-removing
```

I remove my containers like so:

```
docker container rm $(docker container ls -a -q)        
docker image rm $(docker image ls -a -q)
```

I run all my commands with the root account since it's a local temporary machine.

What i've tried myself:

- I tried creating building and removing the container several times. Results are the same consistently.
- I spun up a Ubuntu Server 16.04 LTS machine on Azure, installed docker and tried there. Same result.
- docker system prune. Result is that 0 bytes are reclaimed.

Am I doing something wrong to prevent Docker from cleaning up the files? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Kind regards,
Oskar

Comment: What is your build statement?

Comment: My build statement is: docker build -t helloworldcore .

Comment: Add the output of below commands `docker images`, `docker system prune -f`

Comment: docker images results in an empty list (only the column names). Result of docker system prune -f is: Total reclaimed space: 0B

Comment: Is this fixed with 17.09 version ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Regrettably, it looks like a bug was introduced in Docker 17.06.1 due to some cleanups in the AUFS driver that removed a deferred removal of the renamed "`-removing`" layers (part of an "atomicRemove" strategy in the AUFS graphdriver) if they weren't deleted immediately on exit. This bug is fixed with [PR #34587](https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/34587) which will be in the next patch release of 17.06 as well as in 17.07.

You **might** be able to verify the fix with a nightly from [master.dockerproject.com](https://master.dockerproject.com/) although I am not fully sure what branch that is building from today.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, as least i know it's not a user error on my part. Will wait for the next patch release, i have a workarround to hold me over until then.

Comment: This was 2 years ago, I'm now running Docker version 18.09.2, build 6247962 on Ubuntu 16.04 and my `aufs/diff` folder is still very big (10.5GB) even if I ran `docker system prune`. Any idea what's going on? Is it safe to remove its content manually? I even found a script which is doing that: https://gist.github.com/justlaputa/a50908d4c935f39c39811aa5fa9fba33

Comment: do you have exited containers which have not been removed? `docker ps -a` will show them. `docker system prune -a` will try to remove everything; did you use the "-a" flag? Also you can try to have Docker show you where the disk space is being used: with `docker system df` https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/system_df/